# Allowing Perl Scripts run by Apache to use system()

Tags: linux, perl, apache, soap, system

I Have a perl soap service that I am using to bring together different user's data.  The service works fine, however I would like to run "sort -u file1 file2 > file1" to consolidate the data collected with the data already on the server.  I would like the perl script to call the system function once it has completed it's task

Is this an issue of setting the correct permissions for Apache or something else?

directory listing:

var/www/script.pl
var/www/file1
var/www/file1
var/www/index.php

Any help would be great.  Thanks

Comment: @Prix The files are .csv format. I am not opposed to using something else, it is just that sort -u does a great job.

Comment: @Prix The feature I am really interested in is the sort -u,combining the two files into one and omitting the duplicates.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

```
sort -u file1 file2 > file1
```

Isn't going to do what you say you want it to do. Have you tried it from the command line?

After you run that command, file1 will not contain anything that was in file1 to begin with, because the redirection will clobber file1 before sort gets to act on it.

```
sort -u file1 file2 >file3; mv file3 file1
```

You seem to want to use system(), what happened when you tried it? Did you get any error messages?

Comment: Another way is to use the `-o` parameter: "sort -o file1 file1 file2". This will output to file1, but only after it sorts file1 and file2. It's a relatively unknown trick.

Comment: The problem is not the command.  The command is not being executed so that is not the issue

Answer (score 0):

No, it is an issue of setting the correct permissions for the directory containing the file you want to write.

Find out under which user id/group id the Web server process is running (e.g. by looking at the process table with `/bin/ps -AH -o user,group,cmd`), then refer to [*Controlling Access to Files* in The Linux Cookbook](http://dsl.org/cookbook/cookbook_9.html#SEC131).